# asus xtion pro live working with visp_auto_tracker

Tags: ros, asus-xtion

Not sure if this question has been answered before (please redirect me if it is), but i want to use Asus xtion pro live with visp_auto_tracker to make use of ar markers.

I have used the asus xtion with openni2 and it seems to work, i can view all the topic and the images. however if i try to launch the auto_tracker launch file i get the error :

> Cannot identify '/dev/video0': 2, No such file or directory

which i realize i am missing upon connecting the web cam . however i am able to view the usb device if i use `lsusb`

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1d27:0601 ASUS

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp.

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp.

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

therefore i tried changing the device folder from `/dev/video0` to `/dev/bus/usb/001/009` (after looking at the lsusb) then i am getting some other error:

> VIDIOC_QUERYCAP error 25, Inappropriate ioctl for device

i am unable to find any other solution for this error. from my understanding the web cam is compatible since i am able to use openni2 to launch it but for some reason visp_auto_tracker will have some problem recognizing it .

i have tried usb_cam package and it is giving me the same error . so i am not sure if i need to install some other packages or if this web cam not at all compatible with ros. if there are any solutions to this please help . thank you

some other info :

> package visp_auto_tracker launch file: tracklive_usb.launch
>
> ls -al /dev/video ---> ls: cannot access '/dev/video': No such file or directory
>
> using ubuntu 16.04
>
> using ROS kinetic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asus Xtion Pro does not use standard v4l driver and will be shown as `/dev/video*`, you cannot us standard `usb_cam` to get image. You need to use it's dedicated driver `Openni2` which has a node for ROS called `openni2_launch`. here's the 
[Link to ROS-Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/openni2_launch)

launching this node will results in the image topic you need.

In order to launch `visp_auto_tracker.launch` comment out the `usb_cam` node and replace topics from `openni2_launch` node inside 2 lines:

`<remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/camera_info" to=(#add the relevant topic name from Openni2)/>`

`<remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/image_raw" to=(#add the relevant topic name from Openni2)/>`